# Audio streaming stops whenever I connect to or disconnect from VPN

Tags: sound, vpn, openvpn

I work remotely with a community radio station and stream them regularly because I don't live in their broadcast area. I've noticed the stream stops whenever I connect to or disconnect from a VPN. This happens on both Firefox and Chrome. I'm using the latest browser versions on Ubunutu 20.04.

Any ideas? Could it be something to do with the VPN setup? It doesn't happen when I'm using Windows with the same VPN setup but I'm trying to move away from Windows.

Alan

Comment: I have this happen and its due to the network changing, the stream is going through the VPN while connected to it and then when you disconnect it has to connect again as it is no longer going through the VPN.

Comment: So there's no fix to this?